# debian package creating needed directories in preinst

Tags: debian, package, dpkg

I have the following debian structure:

- debian/usr/share/test
- debian/usr/share/test/test
- debian/usr/share/test/test/a
- debian/usr/share/test/test/b

After building the package using dpkg-deb --build and installing it using dpkg -i, it doesn't seem to create the folders test automatically if they don't exist. Do I need to create them manually in preinst script?

UPDATE: Issue was because preinst had an error so unpacking didn't get a chance to happen.

Laurent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at an example of mine **[here](http://code.google.com/p/erlang-dbus/source/browse/#svn/trunk/project/packages)**.

```
debian/DEBIAN 
debian/usr/bin
debian/usr/lib
```

You have a couple of choices:

1. Populate the directories with the files **before** generating the package (binary package)
2. Build a *source* package where *MAKE* will be called to build the package and install it.

In the first case, you don't need to create the directories through a `preinst` script: the folder hierarchy will be created if necessary by the package manager when the package is installed.

In the second case, you will need to use `mkdir -p` to create the folder hierarchy during the `install` phase.

---

I have been through 3 different ways of packaging for Debian repositories during the last year and believe me, the details to account for are numerous.  One relief was to make the acquaintance of Launchpad and their PPA publishing process.

Comment: In my case, it is a binary package. I have the same structure as yours but when I use dpkg -i, it does not unpack any files or folders.

Comment: There are about 8000 source package -- why don't you pick an existing simple one and look at what it does?  For that reason, we used to have a simple 'hello' package as a working example.

Comment: UPDATE: Issue was because preinst had an error so unpacking didn't get a chance to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You need those in package named either `tmp` or the same as your first package listed in debian/control, depending on which version of the debhelper compat mode you choose.

E.g. a call from one of the `debhelper` example files:

```
$(MAKE) prefix=`pwd`/debian/`dh_listpackages`/usr install
```

You are missing that one level of indirection here.

Comment: Looking at the howto, they say to create the following folder for example:
mkdir -p ./debian/usr/bin
and then ./debian/DEBIAN/control etc...

They don't seem to add the package name before 'debian'.
Am I missing something?

Comment: if i look inside data.tar.gz of my package, i have ./usr/share/test and this is expected if I compare to other debian packages. The question is why dpkg doesn't create /usr/share/test when it unpacks it.